# Vertical in div on mobile device

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap to create `div`. If I access in desktop, `div` shows horizontal, but `div` does not show vertical in mobile browser. I want `div` to show vertical in mobile browser.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >

 <div class="col-sm-pull-0">
     <div class="col-xs-6">
         <!-- content -->
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6">
         <!-- content -->
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'show vertically'? You mean one on top of the other for mobile devices?

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
      //content
 </div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
     //content
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use the wrong classes, http://jsbin.com/weciqava/1 , if you want to show vertically on mobile devices you should use col-xs-12 , if you use xs-6 it shows horizontally